# n52te: program a long mouse button press

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I have a Belkin n52te. I'm using the Razor programming software to program it. What I'd like to do is program it to hold down the right mouse button for 5 seconds and then let go. I've tried recording that, but it didn't work. I've tried putting a 5000 ms delay between the Button Down and the Button Release event but that also didn't work.

Anyone know how to do this? Anyone know of any good forums to search for this?

This is for *Minecraft*. I'd like to make a macro that presses the left mouse button for x number of seconds. Let's say 3. So my macro is:

Left Button Press

3000 ms

Left Button Release

That's exactly what I see on the screen. But that's not what I get when I run the program. I get a single left button press.

The behavior isn't restricted to *Minecraft*. The same thing happens in Notepad++.

Comment: The Belkin n52te is a gamepad. An unusual one, aye, but a gamepad nonetheless. So as a gaming accessory, it's quite fit here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "The behavior isn't restricted to Minecraft. The same thing happens in Notepad++. "

Comment: @pppery I'm thinking this is covered under "Game-specific hardware and utilities". https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: so weird to get a downvote on a 13 year old question; @pppery I didn't need the behavior in Notepad, I needed it for a **game**.

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://www.autohotkey.com/ with the following script:

```
^!b::
    MouseClick, left, , , 1, 0, D
    Sleep 5000
    MouseClick, left, , , 1, 0, U
return
```

This will click the left mouse button for 5 seconds when pressing ctrl-alt-b.

This is regardless of inputdevice. To find out which keycode your device sends use the built in "Key history and script info" and replace the "^!b::" with the keycode found, ex: "SC132::".

More information about MouseClick http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm

Comment: Thought it looked weird, before I noticed the D and U parameter values at the end. (D=Down, U=Up?)

Comment: How does this answer my question about my N52te? Does that program work with the N52te?

Comment: @Jcollum: it emulates mouse clicks, so will work with any mouse.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question: your answer doesn't apply to programming the N52te

Answer (score 0):

I have a Belkin Nostromo n52 and all I have to do is put the delay in as you describe; are you sure it's not working? What if you try changing the n52 macro to use a different key and bind that key in the game in question? Does that work instead? I suppose it could be an issue with their mouse support, which has been flaky at times.

Comment: do you have an n52te? I'm not able to change the bindings for the left mouse button in minecraft.

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't like the n52te because it stripped down so many of the buttons from the Nostromo n52. But I was hoping the software would be identical. Sorry to hear it's not :/